# how to build a source code LV2 plugin for Mac

Tags: audio, build, lv2

I am looking to install a LV2 Plugin I downloaded from GitHub

The Plugin Is the X42 Meter Collection
https://github.com/x42/meters.lv2

How can it be installed?

I am not proficient with computers or command line or terminal and don't know much coding so please give me some simple instructions, thank you. and sorry if I take too much of your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't "proficient with computers" (and then some), you won't be able to build and install plugins from source.  At the very least, you would need to set up a development environment and know your way around the command line, since these plugins have a "classic" UNIX `make` build system.

There are binary releases for most platforms (and other useful information including a FAQ) available for end users at the home page, https://x42-plugins.com/x42/x42-meters